# How can I send a serialized object using cURL for C++?

Tags: c++, curl, post, seal

I am using cURL and Microsoft SEAL in C++. I need to serialize a Ciphertext object to send it to a server through a POST request.

The Ciphertext object is serialized into a `stringstream` but, in order to send it, I need to convert it to a `const char*`. The problem is that, initially, the string obtained from the `stringstream` is 88500 chars long (approx.); but, when converted to `const char*`, it is reduced to 6.

Could the 7th character be '\0', so it is detected as the end of the string? (Both `.c_str()` and `.data()` return the same result.)

```
stringstream st;
cipheredAspirineList[0].save(st);
simplePost("postSingleCipheredAspirine", st.str().c_str());
```

Comment: what is `st.str().size();`? Worth knowing in case the problem is actually earlier than you think.

Comment: I have found that there are '\0' characters in the string, so that is why the conversion to const char* is wrong. My idea is to replace all '\0' for another char, but I do not know which to use, because it must be one that does not belong to the original string. I have checked that, after replacing all '\0' I get the full length string. Now, I am trying to find an unused "temporary" char, in order to rebuild the original string in the server.

Comment: Might be a better idea to go base64 encoding or use something smarter than the, making assumption based on the name here, simple `simplePost`.

Comment: Yesterday, some time before you post your comment I came up with the idea of using the base64 and, even though, the string becomes longer, it worked. By the way, simplePost uses curl library. Thanks for the help